# Computing Element Type When Extending CollectionType

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm trying to implement a protocol that conforms to/extends `CollectionType`, however it doesn't take a single generic type that would obviously be the type of element, so I'd like to be able to compute/force the type of `Generator.Element`.

I'll use a map protocol as an example:

```
protocol Map : CollectionType {
    typealias Key
    typealias Value

    subscript(key:Key) -> Value? { get }
}
```

Is there a way that I can specify that `Self.Generator.Element` must be `(Key, Value)`, other than documentation to type authors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to define a subprotocol of `CollectionType` with additional constraint on `CollectionType.Generator.Element` nested type. This nested type belongs to `CollectionType.Generator` nested type which is constrained to be `GeneratorType`, so in the first place we need to introduce a subprotocol of `GeneratorType` with additional constraint:

```
protocol KeyValueGeneratorType: GeneratorType {

    associatedtype Key
    associatedtype Value

    mutating func next() -> (Key, Value)?

}
```

Then we can introduce a subprotocol of `CollectionType` with additional constraint:

```
protocol KeyValueCollectionType: CollectionType {

    associatedtype Generator: KeyValueGeneratorType

}
```

The `Dictionary` type does in fact conform to our protocol, so we need just a short declaration to manifest this:

```
extension DictionaryGenerator: KeyValueGeneratorType {}
extension Dictionary: KeyValueCollectionType {}
```

Comment: This seems like what I need, but I'm curious, you're using the `associatedtype` keyword but are still referring to generators, should this not either be a `typealias` or refer to Iterators instead?

Comment: In Swift 2.2 the keyword `associatedtype` was introduced to distinguish associated types from type aliases. Please, see this swift-evolution proposal: [Replace typealias keyword with associatedtype for associated type declarations](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0011-replace-typealias-associated.md).

Comment: Ah, I forget I'm still on 2.1 as I decided to wait for Swift 3 before I upgrade (since there are more significant changes to make then anyway).

Anyway, one problem I've encountered with your solution is that there's still no direct connection between `KeyValueGeneratorType.Key` and `KeyValueCollectionType.Key` (they aren't necessarily the same), so I still can't write generic code without doing `where Generator.Key == Self.Key` or similar. Unless I've missed something?

Comment: You missed that `KeyValueCollectionType` has no `Key` nested type, exactly because it's already defined in `Generator` subtype. What you're talking about is like denormalisation and it causes the problems you describe.

Comment: Aha! Right you are, this pattern now seems to be working perfectly, thanks! One note; I did end up having to define a new indexable subscript on my equivalent to `KeyValueCollectionType` in order to get a type-erased wrapper to work, like so: `subscript(position:Index) -> (key:Generator.Key, value:Generator.Value) { get }`, could just be a quirk of my type or wrapper though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the type of generator element you want to conform to. For example.

```
protocol SpecialElement {
    typealias key : Int { get }
    typealias Value : Int { get }
}
```

And then:

```
extension CollectionType where Self.Generator.Element: SpecialElement {
      func addValues() -> Int {
         var total = 0
         for item in self {
           total += item.Value
         }
      return total       
     }
}
```